# Chrome extension: how to capture popup of extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, capture

I am developing extensions for chrome, I need to make that will capture (png screenshot) self- **pop-up of extension window**. Anyone have any ideas?
I know how to do this, just for tabs...
*Sorry for my English.*

Comment: 1. Use [desktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) to capture the entire screen, then crop the popup area (window.screenX, screenY, innerWidth, and innerHeight), 2. Try to use chrome.debugger API to attach to your popup page from your background script and send [Page.captureScreenshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot) command. 3. Use an additional external utility and communicate with it via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: it is a pity that chrome did not provide it natively